How to Import an APL namespace?
Let's say I have the following namespace in the APL file F.apln:
:Namespace F
foo←{...}
:Endnamespace

I want to import this namespace in another namespace and use it. For example:
IMPORT F

:Namespace G
foo2←F.foo∘÷
:Endnamespace

How?

It depends on what exactly you're trying to do.
Adjacent namespaces

:Require file://F.apln

:Namespace G
foo2←##.F.foo∘÷
:Endnamespace

Note the ##. which is necessary to reach out of G as the two namespaces are siblings in the namespace hierarchy.
Nested namespaces

:Namespace G
⎕FIX'file://F.apln'
foo2←F.foo∘÷
:Endnamespace

Amend the path to F.apln if the file isn't in the current directory.
When you do not control the order of loading files (e.g. using Link)

:Namespace G
∇ foo2←foo2
  foo2←##.F.foo∘÷
∇
:Endnamespace

Here, we wrap foo2 in a tradfn so the evaluation of the ##.F reference is deferred to run time.

Thanks Adam! I tried your first method but got ERRORS ENCOUNTERED: ⎕SE.Link.Import: File "/home/zetkhrush/Desktop/apl/src/G.apln" contains a :Require keyword - link must use watch=both. I tried Googling but didn't find anything

@ZetKhrush Sorry, I didn't realise you were using Link. I've never tried using :Require with Link, but from the error message, it sounds like the problem might go away if you install .NET so Link can watch the file system. Meanwhile, I've also added a workaround.

Thanks sir! Im using your tradfns solution
